# Can Eclipse Java Editor Be Formatted Like .NET Between Methods?

Tags: java, vb.net, eclipse

I am really liking the power of Java over VB .NET. But the one thing I dis like are no line breaks between java methods like in VB between subs. Is there a break setting that can mimic VB to make Eclipse look and feel like VB?

Comment: This reminds me of the saying "You can write COBOL in any language". OK not quite the same, since it is about formatting, but I'd recommend not stuffing with the default, and 'go with the flow'.

Comment: What's wrong with just inserting a blank line manually? That's what everyone else is doing, I assume (certainly what I do). Eclipse certainly won't rip it out once it's there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Java Formatter preferences.

Open the Preferences dialog from the Window menu and navigate to Java->Code Style->Formatter (or just type "format" into the search box on the left and pick it). Edit a profile of your own and you *can* set, from the Blank Lines tab, to have one before each method.

Comment: I did not like the look and feel when setting these preferences in eclipse. For me the transition from VB to a Java IDE has been much smoother with Netbeans although it looks like there maybe some limitations for larger projects in Netbeans.